# How can I abort a voice mis-dialed call?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid, voice-command

When I use voice dialing, the wrong contact is selected often enough that I'd like a chance to abort the call before it starts.    If I tap the call button on my headset, it seems to transfer the call back to the phone; by the time I reach for the phone, and hang up, I've left a missed call on a random person's phone.
What is the proper way to abort a call *from the headset* when the dialer picks the wrong contact?   Is there some way to get a bit more delay before the call connects?

Moto Droid (stock), 2.2, Moto H720 headset.

Comment: I can't seem to find anything online about a Motorola H20 headset.  Is that definitely the model number?

Comment: I would personally treat the problem instead of the symptoms ... see if you can get an app that can better recognize your voice or something :)

Comment: @ToxMox It's H720.   Fixed the post.   @Matthew Read -- it's the stock voice dialer.  I do have a number of non-English names in my contact list, I'm not sure if that may be part of the reason for the miscues.

Comment: The new Voice Search is supposed to adjust itself to your voice over time.

Comment: Grrrr -- called "Mehmet" instead of "Marlene" again.   Not sure how it can adjust to my voice if there's no way to give feedback that it got it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up compromising on this by setting Google Voice to "Ask on every call", which gave me a chance to cancel the call.    The downside is having to touch "make call without Google Voice" to put the call through.

Answer (score 1):

On my Spica (Samdroid Froyo Mod), there are two stock voice caller, the Android's stock "Voice Dialer" (`com.android.voicedialer`):

[image: voice dialer icon]

On the stock Android Voice Dialer, when you start the Voice Dialer app and then speak "Call ", this shows up:

[image: voice dialer listening for speech] 
[image: voice dialer cancel]

the stock Voice Dialer can be cancelled by pressing the highlighted "Cancel" button. The Voice Dialer *does not automatically call* the contact, it waits for you to tap on the contact's name to start the call.

The other voice caller is using Google-branded "Voice Search" (`com.google.android.voicesearch`):

[image: voice search box]

when you tap on the Voice Search button on the Google Search Widget and then speak "Call " this screen shows up:

[image: voice search listening for speech]
[image: voice search dialing]

the Google-branded Voice Search *automatically dial after a short delay* the spoken contact, and you can tap "Cancel" before the spinning highlighting is out to cancel the call without leaving missed calls.

I'm not sure which voice dialer you're using, can you clarify?

Comment: It's the stock Bluetooth voice dialer -- which displays a screen like the one on the left if the screen is on and unlocked, except the heading says "Bluetooth Voice Dialer".   I want a way to cancel the call from the headset -- if the phone is in the car dock, I may have to turn on the display, unlock the phone, and then go to the phone app to hang up the call that's connecting.   If the phone is in my jeans pocket under a winter coat, similar problem....

Comment: On my "dumb" Moto Razr, if I tap the call button on the headset after it announces who it's calling, it hangs up without completing a call.   I'd really like something similar here.