# Can Google Voice Search be configured to confirm name before calling?

Tags: google-voice-actions

When making a call using Google Voice Search, I would like my phone to ask for name confirmation.  So, if I say, "call Gina...", I want it to ask me if I meant "call Tina" before dialing.  (suddenly, I feel like I'm in an old Sprint commercial...)

I would like it to confirm ONLY when using voice dialing and would strongly prefer audio prompt.

Comment: Mine already does this. If I say "call Joe" I'm presented with the three or four Joes in my contacts to confirm which one I mean. Are you looking for something different?

Comment: @Al -- I don't recall having ever been prompted like this, except for "Call Joe Mobile or Home?", but then I don't have 4 Joes.   @BCooksey -- I asked a [similar question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3891/how-can-i-abort-a-voice-mis-dialed-call).

Comment: @TomG - thanks.  By the time it's mis-dialed, It's too late for me.  I don't want to risk causing a ring on the other end.

Comment: same here.  When I'm voice dialing, I'm usually driving, and having to grab the phone, unlock the screen and hit the hangup button is a major distraction.  I don't see how it's OK to not have a chance to reject the call before it's made.   I have resorted to removing people from my contacts because they are often enough confused with people I regularly call.

Comment: @TomG - removing contacts... good point.  That would probably have some value for me, even if not the solution I'm looking for.  Not the ultimate solution, but my contact list could use some spring cleaning.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried 3rd-party solutions?  [Call Confirm](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.nanabit.callconfirm) app on the Market seems to do exactly what you need.  I just installed it and can confirm that it works in conjunction with other apps (Voice Search, Google Voice, etc.)

Comment: Just tried it.  It does work with Google Voice and carrier dial.  It is a bit slow, but works.  However, it intercepts EVERY call, whether or not dialed with Google Voice.  Good find!

Comment: It's only slow if you enable the contact name and picture on the prompt.  If you disable it - the prompt is instantaneous, but it only shows the number, which is a bit less helpful.

Comment: For some reason, it only worked the first time I tried it.  Then it started continuously re-prompting for the same call, preventing me from actually making the call.  Uninstalled.

Comment: Yes - for well-known numbers, that works, but I don't always have the recipient's number memorized.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Voice app go to Menu -> More -> Settings -> Making calls -> Ask every time I make a call.  Now you will be presented with a pop-up asking to choose whether or not to use Google Voice for this call.  It doesn't show the name or number you're dialing, but at least it will give you a buffer zone, a chance to cancel a call.

Comment: Clever, but If it doesn't show the name or number, I how will I know it's going to dial the wrong one - and whether or not I want to cancel?.  ;-)

Comment: You're right.  Too bad the prompt covers the name and number.  There might be a way to "skin" that pop-up and make it semi-transparent.  Since the GV app isn't open source, it could be more difficult, but with a help of an app like Ninjamorph it could be possible.  I suggest asking on xda-developers forums for professional help.